# Can I make this Ruby code faster and/or use less memory?

Tags: ruby, arrays, performance

I have an `Array` of `String` objects in Ruby which are made up of words like the one below:

`animals = ["cat horse", "dog", "cat dog bird", "dog sheep", "chicken cow"]`

I want to convert this to another `Array` of `String` objects but with only one animal per element and only unique elements.  I found one way to do this as follows:

```
class Array
  def process()
    self.join(" ").split().uniq
  end
end
```

However, if the input array is huge, let's say millions of entries then performance of this will be pretty bad because I'll be creating a huge string, then a huge array and then `uniq` has to process that huge array to remove duplicate elements.  One way I was thinking of speeding things up was to create a `Hash` with an entry for each word, that way I'd only process each word once on the first pass.  Is there a better way?

Comment: If possible set the encoding to ASCII-8BIT to reduce the amount of memory.

Comment: @steenslag That's bad advice. In UTF-8, every [ISO 8859-1](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO/IEC_8859-1) (a.k.a. Latin 1) character is encoded as 8 bits (hence the name). ISO 8859-1 includes the entire ASCII character set (and is ASCII compatible, i.e. `ñ` is `0xF1` (`0b11110001`) in ASCII, ISO 8859-1 and UTF-8). Using ASCII-8BIT will not save any memory.

Comment: @Jordan: Um, no. UTF-8 is a variable length encoding system where having the right bit set means "this character isn't finished yet so keep going to the next byte". `"\xf1"` is not valid UTF-8 at all. The UTF-8 representation of `ñ` is in fact `\xC3\xB1`. They do overlap in the (7-bit) ASCII range though.

Comment: @muistooshort You're right, I was not quite correct (and my example was completely wrong—in fact, `ñ` can't be encoded in ASCII_8BIT). However, "use ASCII_8BIT to save memory" is still terrible advice, unless OP is sure he'll never encounter any characters that aren't ASCII. In Ruby `Encoding::ASCII_8BIT` is intended for raw binary data (it's an alias for `Encoding::BINARY`), not text. It would be a very, very special corpus for which ASCII_8BIT would give a more than negligible advantage over UTF8.

Comment: @Jordan: A UTF-8 `ñ` can be encoded in binary just fine, it just takes two bytes. If your source text is in one of the 8859 or Windows-CP encodings then that `ñ` (assuming it is available at all) will only take one byte if the string is treated as binary. So, if your source text is UTF-8 and contains non-ASCII characters then switching to binary won't save anything; if your source text is in ASCII or an 8-bit encoding and contains non-ASCII characters then bypassing UTF-8 could save you quite a bit of memory. Reading the data in binary could  save some time when reading too.

Comment: @muistooshort Like I said, a very special corpus. At any rate it's a really premature optimization.

Comment: The very special corpus I have tried this with was DNA encoding - just four chars. I don't know much about encodings and it was a few years ago, and not production code. I remember saving about 50% memory, but I can't reproduce the results on Ruby 2.1.3. So maybe Ruby is optimized by now, and my advice is indeed useless.

Comment: @steenslag: I don't know if I'd say useless. It really depends on the corpus in question. Optimization is a bit of a black art and the answer is usually some variation of "it depends".

Comment: Have you tried using `flat_map(&:split).uniq` or variants off that?

Comment: Yeah, performance was on a par with the best ones here but not as good as the original

Comment: @steenslag You could have saved another 75% of that memory by encoding each DNA base in two bits. ;) Anyway, the characters `A`, `C`, `G` and `T` have the same encoding in ASCII and UTF-8, which doesn't have anything to do with Ruby being optimized or not. Maybe you were thinking of UTF-16 or UTF-32?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You've got the right idea. However, Ruby has a built-in class that's perfect for building sets of unique items: [Set](http://www.ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.1.3/libdoc/set/rdoc/Set.html).

```
animals = ["cat horse", "dog", "cat dog bird", "dog sheep", "chicken cow"]

unique_animals = Set.new

animals.each do |str|
  unique_animals.merge(str.split)
end
# => cat
#    horse
#    dog
#    bird
#    sheep
#    chicken
#    cow
```

Or...

```
unique_animals = animals.reduce(Set.new) do |set, str|
  set.merge(str.split)
end
```

Under the covers Set [actually uses a Hash](https://github.com/ruby/ruby/blob/trunk/lib/set.rb#L81) to store its items, but it acts more like an un-ordered Array and responds to all of the familiar Enumerable methods (`each`, `map`, `select`, etc.). If you need to turn it into a real Array, though, just use [Set#to_a](http://www.ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.1.3/libdoc/set/rdoc/Set.html#method-i-to_a).

Comment: I tried this out and in practice it doesn't seem to perform better.  My benchmark results are here:
      user     system      total        real
 New:
  0.000000   0.000000   0.000000 (  0.003199)
 Old:
  0.000000   0.000000   0.000000 (  0.000267)

Comment: @conorgriffin: `set += array` is probably going to be more expensive than `set.merge(array)` due to all copying.

Comment: I'm not surprised given the very small sample. I recommend the [benchmark-ips](https://github.com/evanphx/benchmark-ips) gem, which usually gives much smarter results for code like this. It shows the optimized version is 50x faster. https://gist.github.com/jrunning/2bf920bd438336c2be48

Comment: P.S. Don't take this the wrong way, but your Ruby style is kind of... weird. For one thing, in idiomatic Ruby it's very rare to see empty parentheses in method calls or definitions (i.e. prefer `str.split` over `str.split()`). GitHub maintains a [Ruby Styleguide](https://github.com/styleguide/ruby) that I highly recommend.

Comment: Sorry, yeah I'm new to Ruby so I'm still getting to grips with leaving brackets out and not explicitly returning :)

Comment: Hmmm, I commented on your gist.  Are you missing `|times|` for the older method in the Benchmark?

Comment: Good eye. That should be omitted for both since I'm not using it. I don't *think* it would change the result but I'm not at a computer anymore so I can't check just now.

Comment: :o/ turns out it makes the difference.  Removing `|times|` from the first method results in the new method being ~2.5x slower than the old one.  The new one probably uses less memory for large inputs but it's not faster...

Comment: Ha. I guess it's just not my day!

Answer (score 3):

Surprisingly (maybe), I don't think you'll be able to go faster than you present code does. I think your code is the fastest and the most readable at the same time. Here is why: your code expresses a pretty good high level algorithm that can be *directly mapped into Ruby high level methods*. These methods are optimized and compiled. Good luck implementing faster ones in pure Ruby. In any case, I am by no means a Ruby guru, and I would be very interested to see a more performant solution on reasonable size arrays.

Jordan and Nathaniel implemented solutions that are indeed more granular and that process the input array iteratively "by hand". While this *may* use less memory, it won't be as fast as Ruby's `uniq`. But if you experience memory problems with large arrays (or performance problems when you reach some threshold), of course you should consider implementing variations on those. Here is mine:

```
def process
  distincts = Hash.new
  self.each { |words| words.split.each { |word| distincts[word] = nil }}
  distincts.keys
end
```

This is Jordan's solution, using a Hash instead of a Set. That's what you intended to use. Directly using a Hash will eliminate the overhead of maintaining the Set (or so I suppose), and should be noticeably faster. A slightly even faster solution might be:

```
def process
  distincts = Hash.new
  self.each { |words| words.split.each { |word| distincts[word] = :present unless distincts[word] }}
  distincts.keys
end
```

Again, I'm not sure about that (I'm sorry, I can't test all that easily right now). Anyway, I suspect one of these two to be closer to your original code's performances, but I doubt it will overcome it (again, until you hit a certain input size).

Comment: This is better than the other suggestions, it's still slower than my original method though.  See the gist https://gist.github.com/conorgriffin/0a6cecc8f0ebf5c3ca63

Comment: Yes, I am not surprised. As I said, you'll hardly find a better solution than your first thought. Even on very large arrays (and as long as memory space is not a problem), this "Hash version" is unlikely to perform better than yours, though I think it will equal it from the moment it reach a certain array size. Anyway, your implementation is definitely the right choice if memory usage is not an issue.

Comment: This is a very thoughtful answer, Patrice. Your intuition about using Hash instead of a Set was correct, by the way. I benchmarked it and the the original method was still fastest, with the Hash and Set methods 1.7x and 2.9x slower, respectively. https://gist.github.com/jrunning/2bf920bd438336c2be48

Answer (score 0):

Why not process each array element yourself?

```
for each element in [...]
  if the element does not contain spaces
    insert it into the result array
  else
    split it up and insert its parts in the next position ahead
  end
end
```

The following is a ruby implementation:

```
class Array
  def process
    d = dup
    d.each_with_object([]).each_with_index do |(element, array), index|
      if !element.index " "
        array << element if !array.include? element
      else
        d.insert index+1, *(element.split)
      end
    end
  end
end

["cat horse", "dog", "cat dog bird", "dog sheep", "chicken cow"].process
=> ["cat", "horse", "dog", "bird", "sheep", "chicken", "cow"]
```

Advantages:

- You don't have to process long strings
- As close to linear time as possible (see disadvantages)
- Maintains element order

Disadvantages:

- Slightly slower than linear time (due to how strings are split and inserted ahead)

That said, it's a hell of a lot faster than `join(" ").split().uniq` (fewer loops). But then it's faster in a practical sense, not a scientific sense.

Comment: "A hell of a lot faster in a practical sense"? I seriously doubt that. I suspect it would be (a lot) slower than OP's solution, and most probably slower than Jordan's one. Array searches and insertions will be serious bottlenecks here.

Comment: I'm afraid your solution is much slower (5x) than the original one

Comment: Huh. I never benchmarked it. It is less iteration-heavy.

Answer (score 0):

I've tried various methods suggested by others here but I've come up with two that are faster than the others suggested here but not as fast as the original unfortunately.

```
  # This one moves through the original Array using inject to process
  # each element containing space-separated words and appending them
  # to a new array.  Finally uniq is called to remove duplicate words
  def process_new_4
    self.inject([]) {
        |array, words|
      array.push(*words.split)
    }.uniq
  end

  # This one uses the flat_map method of Array to flatten itself, each
  # element is split in case it contains more than one word, then the
  # flattened array has duplicate elements removed with uniq
  def process_new_3
    self.flat_map(&:split).uniq
  end
```

Comment: Look at that, both of them use Ruby's `uniq`! These are not really other methods. Well, only other methods for splitting strings. You will find dozens other ways to split strings in Ruby, but the real work is done in the `uniq` part. This is were all other implementations will fall short.

Comment: By the way, did you try on very big arrays to see if the gap is still significant?

Comment: I've run several tests, some with 5,000-30,000 elements (containing 1-5 words per element) and some with 1,000,000 elements (again with 1-5 words per element).